# How to draw detected keypoints on an image in java/javacv?

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, feature-detection, keypoint

Can anyone tell me that how can i detect keypoints of an image and draw that keypoints on that image in java?
I tried smt but i couldn't figure out how to draw them?
Any ideas for how should i proceed or any ideas for drawing for my code?

```
final IplImage image1 = cvLoadImage(
                "C:/Users/Can/Desktop/panorama_image1.jpg",
                CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

        final CanvasFrame canvas1 = new CanvasFrame("Image1");

        canvas1.showImage(image1);

        canvas1.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        SIFT sift = new SIFT();

        KeyPoint keypoint1 = new KeyPoint();

        sift.detect(image1, null, keypoint1);

        System.out.println("Keypoints for image1: " + keypoint1.capacity());
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you or anyone else still requires this, you can do the following.

Using Java, after you have computed your keypoints you can do the following using the `Features2d` class in OpenCV.

```
    // draw keypoints on image
    Mat outputImage = new Mat();
    // Your image, keypoints, and output image
    Features2d.drawKeypoints(image, keypoints, outputImage);
    String filename = "keypoints.jpg";
    System.out.println(String.format("Writing %s...", filename));
    Highgui.imwrite(filename, outputImage);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you or others still need an answer, I believe the possible way of doing that is

```
opencv_features2d.drawKeypoints(_image1, keypoint1, Mat.EMPTY);
```

Then you may save your `_image1` to file using

`ImageIO.write(_image1.getBufferedImage(), "png", new File("image1.png"));`

But before that you'll have to open your `image1` as a Mat object: 
`Mat _image1 = new Mat(image1);`